# querying on internals in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have document structure like:

```
    { "_id": { "$oid" : "51711cd87023380037000001" }, 
    "dayData": "{ "daysdata":{"date":"02-12-2013","week_day":"","month":"","date_day":"","year":"2013"}}" 
    }
```

I want to extract document having date = "02-12-2013" in the above. Here i am trying to query on a value which is also a json.
Please let me know how to use mongodb java driver to extract this

Comment: Are you fetching data from JSON or MongoDB ?

Comment: i am fetching data from mongodb. This is the document structure stored in mongodb.

Comment: Is the `dayData` field really a JSON string?

Comment: I would suggest that in your application, you parse the JSON string to extract the objects and create a subdocument which you will put in the `dayData` field. Things would be much easier to query if that's the case.

Comment: Or, why don't you just save the only `date` in ISO format is a single field like `"dayData" : ISODate(...)`. Day, month, etc. values will be easy to compute.

Answer (score 0):

**Not answer** (stackoverflow won't let me *comment* as I don't have enough points!)

Your string containing  json has a syntax error.
There is a single `"` after `"year":"2013"`

You may have to fix that 1st.