# can we query on key inside the value

Tags: mongodb

In my document if the value of a key is itself a json(having key-value).
how do i search on the key of the document inside the value.

for ex:

```
    { "_id": { "$oid" : "51711cd87023380037000001" }, 
    "dayData": "{ "daysdata":{"date":"02-12-  2013","week_day":"","month":"","date_day":"","year":"2013"}}" 
    }
```

If i have multiple documents like this and i want to get the document having date "02-12-  2013". My return value should be the value of key daydata using mongodb java driver

Comment: possible duplicate of [querying on internals in mongo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140978/querying-on-internals-in-mongo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dot-notation, so in your case:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({'dayData.daysdata.date': 1});
```

and then

```
db.collection.find({'dayData.daysdata.date': 02-12-2013});
```

as an example:

```
> db.test.insert({x: {x: {x: 1}}})
> db.test.insert({x: {x: {x: 2}}})
> db.test.insert({x: {x: {x: 3}}})
>
> db.test.ensureIndex({'x.x.x': 1})
> 
> db.test.find({'x.x.x': 2}, {_id: false})
  {"x" : { "x" : { "x" : 2} } }
>
```

proof that it uses the index:

```
> db.test.find({'x.x.x': 2}, {_id: false}).explain()
  {
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor x.x.x_1",
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
        ....
  }
>
```